# disable crontab auto generate file in home directory

Tags: php, cron, wget

I have a cron job for

*/5 * * * * wget --post-data="pass=1123&Type=111" http://test.biz/index.php/game_line

which triggered by myaccount

and I have saw a lot of files for empty content locate in my home directory
game_line.1
game_line.100
game_line.1000
....

what are these for? and How can I turn off this files be generated?

thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those files are what you downloaded using that `wget` command. `wget` queries a url and saves the response as a file. You asked it to. If, as typical for usage within a cron job, you are *not* interested in the response you must tell the system to ignore the response, to throw it away:

```
*/5 * * * * wget --post-data="pass=1123&Type=111" http://test.biz/index.php/game_line 2>&1 1>/dev/null
```